# Stop my JavaScript from displaying the drop-down value?

Tags: javascript

Currently my JS code outputs the value of whatever was selected, how can I stop that from happening? I seem to have lost it in my JS code.

I do not want it to write the output of the drop-down anymore.

```
<!-- The first select list -->
<select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
    <option>- - -</option>
    <option value="amazon">Amazon</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="keurig">Keurig</option>
    <option value="nike">Nike</option>
</select>

<!-- Tags for the seccond dropdown list, and for text-content -->
<span id="slist2"></span> <div id="scontent"></div>


<script><!--
    /* Script Double Select Dropdown List, from: coursesweb.net/javascript/ */
    var SList = new Object();             // JS object that stores data for options

    // HERE replace the value with the text you want to be displayed near Select
    var txtsl2 = '';

    /*
    Property with options for the Seccond select list
    The key in this object must be the same with the values of the options added in the first select
    The values in the array associated to each key represent options of the seccond select
    */
    SList.slist2 = {
        "amazon": ['Kindle Fire HD', 'Kindle Charger', 'Kindle Fire HDX'],
        "apple": ['MacBook', 'iMac', 'iPhone', 'iPad'],
        "keurig": ['Platinum', 'Vue'],
        "nike": ['Fuel Band']
    };


    /*
    Property with text-content associated with the options of the 2nd select list
    The key in this object must be the same with the values (options) added in each Array in "slist2" above
    The values of each key represent the content displayed after the user selects an option in 2nd dropdown list
    */

    SList.scontent = {
        "Kindle Fire HD": 'kindlefirehd',
        "Kindle Charger": 'kindlecharg',
        "Kindle Fire HDX": 'kindlefirehdx',
        "MacBook": 'macbook',
        "iMac": 'imac',
        "iPhone": 'iphone',
        "iPad": 'ipad',
        "Platinum": 'platinum',
        "Vue": 'vue',
        "FuelBand": 'fuelband'
    };

    /* From here no need to modify */

    // function to get the dropdown list, or content
    SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
        document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = '';           // empty option-content

        if(SList[slist][option]) {
            // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
            if(slist == 'scontent'){ document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];
                var selected = SList[slist][option];
                functions[selected]();
            }
            else if(slist == 'slist2') {
                var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
                for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
                    addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
                }
                document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
            }
        }
        else if(slist == 'slist2') {
            // empty the tag for 2nd select list
            document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }

    var functions = {
        kindlefirehd: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        kindlecharge: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        kindlefirehdx: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        macbook: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        imac: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        iphone: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        ipad: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        platinum: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        vue: function(){window.alert("func1 called")},
        fuelband: function(){window.alert("func1 called")}
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Outputs how? To the console? As an alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the second selection text going in to the span "scontent"-

In SList.getSelect it is in this chunk of code:

```
        if(SList[slist][option]) {
        // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
        if(slist == 'scontent'){ /* from here */ document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option]/* to here */;
            var selected = SList[slist][option];
            functions[selected]();
        }
```

If you remove the code in between my comments it should stop writing it to the span.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it seems to be this line.

```
document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
```

Hope it helps. I will check back in later to give a more thorough answer if needed.